# how to set footer at the bottom when there is no content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
<footer>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <p>Designed by <a href="http://wiredelta.com/" target="_blank">Wiredelta</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="pull-right barMain">
        <ul class="social-bar">
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

not getting footer at bottom of the page when there is no content is present in the body.so i need to fix footer at the bottom only, when i run the code the code.plzz give suggestion how to fix footer at the bottom exactly.

Comment: Do you need position: fixed?

Answer (score 1):

**A) Footer is fixed:**

```
footer {
    background-color: skyblue;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
footer {
 background-color: skyblue;
 position:fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<footer>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <p>Designed by <a href="http://wiredelta.com/" target="_blank">Wiredelta</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="pull-right barMain">
        <ul class="social-bar">
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**B) Footer is not fixed:**

```
body {
    height: 1200px;
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    background-color: skyblue;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  background-color: skyblue;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<footer>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <p>Designed by <a href="http://wiredelta.com/" target="_blank">Wiredelta</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="pull-right barMain">
        <ul class="social-bar">
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-stack back-fa "><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

just add this in your css.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options from which I would suggest using flex-box.

#### 1. position: fixed

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

#### 2. Flex-box

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <main></main>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/marcobiedermann/pen/XpoarE

#### 3. Table

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <main></main>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

main: {
    height: 100%;
}

footer {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/marcobiedermann/pen/jImsc